# Jquery video button trigger issue

Tags: jquery, html, video, html5-video

I'm trying to toggle pause/play of a background video via either clicking the video or via a button. 
I've managed to get the video click trigger to work, but can't figure out how to do the button part. I'm learning jquery so still a bit of a novice!

Here's what I've got so far:

```
$("video").trigger("play");//for auto play
$("video").addClass('pause');//for check pause or play add a class
$('video').click(function() {
if ($(this).hasClass('pause')) {
 $("video").trigger("play");
 $(this).removeClass('pause');
 $("#artwork").removeClass('fadein')
 $(this).addClass('play');
 pauseButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
} else {
 $("video").trigger("pause");
 $(this).removeClass('play');
 $(this).addClass('pause');
 $("#artwork").addClass('fadein');
 pauseButton.innerHTML = "Paused";
}
});
```

Any help is appreciated! 
Cheers

Comment: `how to do the button part` What do you mean?

Comment: I can't figure out how to add to that script to trigger the video to stop and stop with a button. Should of been clearer. Apologies.

Comment: This what I've tried but it doesn't work very well:      $("video").trigger("play");//for auto play
$('video, #play-pause').click(function() {
if ($('video').hasClass('pause')) {
     $("video").trigger("play");
     $(this).removeClass('pause');
     $("#artwork").removeClass('fadein')
     $(this).addClass('play');
} else {
     $("video").trigger("pause");
     $(this).removeClass('play');
     $(this).addClass('pause');
     $("#artwork").addClass('fadein');
}
});

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you already handle the click even on video and it works. So just do the same for your pauseButton. Move click-related code to some function, and bind it as a callback for whatever trigger you like- click on video, click on button, etc. So, minimally updating your code:

```
function toggleVideo() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('pause')) {
    $("video").trigger("play");
    $(this).removeClass('pause');
    $("#artwork").removeClass('fadein')
    $(this).addClass('play');
    pauseButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
  } else {
    $("video").trigger("pause");
    $(this).removeClass('play');
    $(this).addClass('pause');
    $("#artwork").addClass('fadein');
    pauseButton.innerHTML = "Paused";
  }
};

$('video').click(toggleVideo); // handle click on video
// assuming pauseButton references your play/pause button
$(pauseButton).click(toggleVideo); // handle click on button
$("video").trigger("play"); // for auto play
$("video").addClass('pause'); // for check pause or play add a class
```